# Is there a POSIX-compliant way of getting local network IP address of my computer?

Tags: c, posix

I know this question has been asked a million times in one form or another, but no question gave me a POSIX-compliant way of doing it.

I need to get the local network address of my computer **without** using `getifaddrs` or any other non POSIX-compliant way of accessing interfaces. Is that possible ?

Comment: If you're using a socket to communicate with a remote host, getsockname() should give you the local address for this socket.

Comment: There's no such thing as **the** local network address. About every computer system with network enabled has a loopback adapter (localhost, typically `127.0.0.1` or `::1` but could be others) and one or more actual network interfaces with each one or more IPv4 and IPv6 addresses (or other protocols). If you only want to deal with one address only, you either have to pick one of these using some heuristics or have the user decide which one she wants to use.

Comment: If you're root ... `system("ifconfig eth1 | grep 'inet addr' | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1")` or `popen()`

Comment: pmg: In which way is ifconfig posix compliant exactly ?

Comment: @pmg While `ifconfig` is pretty standard and the **current** best approach, some Linux distros for example are starting to come without `ifconfig`, providing only `iproute2`. Personally I would go with `SIOCGIFCONF`.

Comment: @HolgerJust : I know about the fact that there is no unique local network adress. Still doesn't answer my question though. If i could get any of them it would be okay. Seems i just can't

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no direct support for such a thing but you can use udp sockets (`SOCK_DGRAM`) to `connect` to a known distant address. Since udp sockets are stateless this doesn't do any network traffic.

Then you can query for the local endpoint of that socket (`getsockname`) to obtain the local IP adress through which your system would route. Again since udp is stateless this just queries your local routing tables and no real network traffic is issued.

Don't forget to close the socket after that.

Remote public nameservers are good for that purpose. You can test for several of them

- one of them might occasionally be down or there might be no route for
  some reason to that part of the world
- your process may be on the same local network as the server and you
  might only obtain some special local address
- test for IPv4 and IPv6 addresses

Comment: Why does it matter if one is down? The route should always exist anyway. `8.8.8.8` is an easy one to remember, btw..

Comment: @R.., google's nameserver is one possible choice, yes. I added more reasons why it might be appropriate to check for several servers. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not possible, as posix does not specify any API to access that information.

Unixes typically support getifaddrs, or the SIOCGIFCONF ioctl , so use one of them or some other system demendant API. Note that there can be (and usually are) several network interfaces on a machine, and you have to figure out which you're interested in.

Comment: +1 But I wonder if there's a nice little library to abstract this away. Although (in my admittedly little experience) I haven't met a Unix without `SIOCGIFCONF`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This isn't for any real world programming, or i would have settled for getifaddrs already. It is for an assignment where i am supposed to use POSIX compliant calls only. I guess my teacher didn't check if what he asked was possible or not.

Comment: wrong answer. There is no direct API for that, correct, but there are other ways to achieve that. Please see my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Quite simple, surely:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  return 8 == write(1, "0.0.0.0\n", 8) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

POSIX has no concept of "network", even less IP. So no.

Besides, a machine can have lots of network addresses (at least loopback, one or several for each network card, at least three IPv6 addresses, ...), "*the* network address" isn't well defined anyway.

Comment: This is, why you should "connect" a UPD socket to a given <addr>. The OS selects the right interface to route <addr> and "getsockname" will get you the source IP of the selected interface.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   printf("127.0.0.1\n");
}
```

Comment: @Jens: The loopback address is a perfectly valid local network address.

Comment: it is just that your answer is not really helpful for the OP. One could even interpret it that you are making fun out of him, although his question is a valid and interesting one. And technically your answer would only be correct if you also check if the loopback is configured. Also it could be set to any other `127` address, `127.0.0.0` is a class A network. It is only for IPv6 that `::1` is always a valid address.