# use of rtnetlink library to determine src address

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ipv6

If i have an destination address is it possible that with rtnetlink library I could determine that which source address would be used while sending the data to this destination. I don't think any use cases of it for ipv4 address but in case of ipv6 it is useful. If yes it would nice if you can provide some sample code on how it could be done.

Comment: What's wrong with just binding & connecting to an arbitrary port via UDP then getting the socket name of the local socket? It will bind to the relevant local address and you can get the address from that

Comment: Why not just call `getaddrinfo()`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I use the connect to port 0 over UDP on a remote system to determine the IP address to connect back to when driving GUI tests. This is generally because getaddrinfo(hostname) returns 127.0.0.1/::1 because of /etc/hosts files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a POSIX-compliant way of getting local network IP address of my computer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645566/is-there-a-posix-compliant-way-of-getting-local-network-ip-address-of-my-compute)

Comment: @Michael getaddrinfo just helps you to determine the destination address and not the source address.So can't use that.

Comment: @Petesh what you said won't work for some application say an VOIP Application. Where your source address and port should not change.

Comment: @SeanBright Not at all an duplicate what's in that question is my fellow friend has asked for an POSIX library. And that too he is intereseted to retrieve an local ipv4 address. My question is for netlink (library which is different from POSIX) and also what i want is an ipv6 address. And this address should be determined depending upon the destination address. By applying source address selection algorithm of RFC3484.

Comment: Done, finally I made it worked. You can use rtnetlink library to determine the most preferred source address.

Comment: @rahul09 ... and then you post the answer so that other people can find it should they want it